# Redirect outside WP after Login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I have http://mysite.com/admin.php

There I check wether the user is admin or not.
In second case I send the user to the wp-login page like this:

```
blog.mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com/admin.php
```

I expect redirect back for admin.php but wordpress always send me to wp-admin control panel.

I have researched.
When the dest. host is not in filter

> allowed_redirect_hosts

WP just redirect the user to wp-admin.

How can I add more hosts to the filter?

If I put this example from the WP Codex on functions.php it stops working.

> (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/allowed_redirect_hosts)

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts' , 'my_allowed_redirect_hosts' , 10 );
function my_allowed_redirect_hosts($content){
    $content[] = 'blog.example.com';
    $content[] = 'codex.example.com';
    // wrong: $content[] = 'http://codex.example.com';
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your `functions.php`:

```
function my_allowed_redirect_hosts($allowed_host) {
    $allowed_host[] = 'anothersite.com';
    $allowed_host[] = 'www.someotherwebsite.com';
    return $allowed_host;
}
add_filter('allowed_redirect_hosts','my_allowed_redirect_hosts');
```

Replace `anothersite.com` and add new values accordingly.

---

If you're trying to redirect users in a normal page, you can make use of Wordpress's `wp_redirect()` function:

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

Documentation: [**`wp_redirect()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isnt it what i said it didnt work? It breaks functions.php :(

Comment: I tested the function, and it works exactly as it is supposed to. It is probably something with your theme. Change your theme to the default one (Twenty Twelve), add the code in `functions.php`, save it, and go to the link. It should work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works!
What I was doing wrong is putting the code in the WP functions.php file, and not in my custom theme functions.php file.

Thanks all!